# C++ GMP Library ostream operator<< compiles but doesn't link?

Tags: c++, linux, gmp

```
$ apt-cache show libgmp10
Package: libgmp10
...
Version: 2:5.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu2
```

**test.cpp**:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpz_class x = 42;

    cout << x;
}
```

**compile:**

```
$ g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
$
```

OK

**link:**

```
$ g++ test.o -lgmp
test.o: In function `std::ostream& operator<<
    <__mpz_struct [1]>(std::ostream&,
         __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1],
              __mpz_struct [1]> const&)':

test.cpp:(.text._ZlsIA1_12__mpz_structERSoS2_RK10__gmp_exprIT_S4_E[_ZlsIA1_12__mpz_structERSoS2_RK10__gmp_exprIT_S4_E]+0x2a):

undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, __mpz_struct const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It can't find `operator<<(ostream&, mpz_class)` at link time.  What gives?

Comment: when in doubt just verify the right options with pkg-config ( if the lib uses pkg-config )

Comment: @user1824407: `pkg-config libgmp10` returns nothing ?

Comment: it's more common than you think that the package name is different from the lib-name, sometimes even the name in the flag is different. i suggest `pkg-config --list-all | grep -i gmp` pick the `rightName` from the results and `pkg-config --cflags rightName` for the inclusions `pkg-config --libs rightName` for the libs

Comment: @user1824407: `pkg-config --list-all | grep -i gmp` returns nothing

Comment: `dpkg -L libgmp10` returns a `pkg-config` configuration file (.pc extension) ?

Comment: i have just tried this on my Ubuntu machine and looks like gmp is part of the gcc toolchain by default and your source file generates an `a.out` executable with `g++ main.cpp -lgmpxx`

Comment: @user1824407: Yes that is correct.  With `-lgmpxx` the toy example works, with `-lgmp` it doesn't.  The real codebase only compiles with BOTH `-lgmp` AND `-lgmpxx` for some reason.

Answer (score 13):

You need to link the C++ library as well as the C library:

```shell
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o -lgmpxx -lgmp
#                         ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Actually it looks like I need to mention both

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: Hm, I see. Try `ldd` on `libgmpxx.so` and see if `libgmp.so` appears as a dependency. It does for me.

Comment: It does have the dependency and in the toy example it works but I get link errors in the larger project without both: `/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1984: undefined reference to __gmpf_clear`.  Odd

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: Oh OK, I see. I suppose that you're fine as long as you only use functions that are wrapped by the C++ interface, but if you use C functions directly then those dependencies have to be met explicitly. I've updated the post.

Comment: You need -lgmp for almost anything, like +, or creating a variable. gmpxx.h consists almost only of inline functions that call the C functions (I/O is one of the few exceptions). Some systems can be confusing because when you link with libgmpxx.so they automatically link with its dependencies (libgmp.so in particular) so you don't notice that you really should add -lgmp explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164556/1824407) I can confirm 2 things from my experiments with this:

1. the inclusions are the same for both `-lgmp` and `-lgmpxx` because the output of `g++ -M main.cpp -lgmp` is the same of `g++ -M main.cpp -lgmpxx`
2. g++/gcc uses different libs for this 2 flags because `g++ main.cpp -Wl,-t -lgmp` is different from `g++ main.cpp -Wl,-t -lgmpxx` and only the last one works

I have no experience with GMP but since this directories are hard-coded in the gcc configuration, at least in this Ubuntu build, you need to make the gcc output more verbose and use a lot of patience to parse all the output and maybe you will find the real reason for this.